# Android Spinner text color in dark mode

Tags: android, spinner, android-darkmode

I'm about to implement the dark theme in my Android app.
The problem, I've got is the text color of my selected spinner. -> It is "Black" as the background...
This problem occurs if I set the values of the spinner programmatically. If I set them in the xml, the color of the text is white, as expected.
If I open the spinner, the text color of the selectable items is correctly whitt.
In the bright mode, the text is displayed with a back color and a white background
This is my code:

```
    mSearchServiceFilterSpinner = findViewById(R.id.services);
    ArrayAdapter<SearchService> mSessionDropdownAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<SearchService>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, searchServices) {  // searchServices is my ArrayList with the selectable items.
        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View v = super.getDropDownView(position, null, parent);
            // If this is the selected item position
            v.setBackgroundColor(searchServices.get(position).getColor());  // Not important for the question
            return v;
        }
    };
```

What am I missing? Why does it work if I set it via the spinner xml `android:entries="@array/array_name"`, but not if I set it programmatically?

Comment: pls fix your images

Comment: @FariborZ: It link to the pictures does not work. Neither drag and drop nor select. It worked the first time. I removed them now.